# error happening after I add new parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, jasmine, mocha.js

I had a test case working fine, but after adding an extra parameter `tiger` to my method `swiming`, it's breaking.

I even passed the new parameter `tiger` to my test case but still it's breaking.

**update** 
I am getting grid undefined  at this line...any idea now how to proceed   let grid = $('#henTigerGrid').data('kendoGrid');

```js
let tiger = {
    "nail": "hens/v1/sky/88888888888888",
    "columns": [],
    "title": "DOCUMENTS",
    "excelFileName": "ViewAiringsExport",
    "mainId": 88888888888888
};
```

Code is below:

---

**Error**

```
[0] 14 09 2017 19:56:26.250:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Desktop/08-31-afternoon/webcomponent/src/main/webapp/app/components/finan    LOG: 'model.skyName--->text.txt'
    LOG: 'tiger.naile---->hens/v1/sky/88888888888888'
    Chrome 60.0.3112 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Jasmine Unit Tests: Help-Dashboard-Manage-Tiger Add start Finger FAILED
[0]     TypeError: Cannot read property '_data' of undefined
    Chrome 60.0.3112 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 14 of 29 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 2.796 secs)
```

---

**Code**

```
swiming(evt, dropValue, tiger) {
    let todayDate = this.todayDate();
    let grid = $('#henTigerGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    let _dataSource = grid.dataSource;
    let pageSize = _dataSource.pageSize();

    //console.log("_dataSource._data---->" + _dataSource._data.length);

    let gridLength = _dataSource._data.length;
    let filename;

    console.log("loggedUserName---->" + $(".loggedUserName").text());

    let attributes=this.sportsService.getSeesionStorageValue();

    if(attributes) {
        this.parrotrId = attributes.parrotr_attributes.SSO[0];
        this.loggedUserName = attributes.parrotr_attributes.DisplayName[0];
    }

    if(this.fileSelect == null || this.fileSelect == "") {
        _dataSource.insert(gridLength, {
            "skyId": "104",
            "skyName": filename,
        });
    } else {
        let temparry = [];
        let attributes = this.sportsService.getSeesionStorageValue();
        let lastIndex = this.fileSelect.lastIndexOf(".");

        if(lastIndex >= 0) {
            filename = this.fileSelect; //.substring(lastIndex,0);
        }

        var fileSize = 0;
        fileSize = fileSize / 1048576; //size in mb

        let k = _dataSource._data.length;

        _dataSource.insert(k, {
            "skyId": "105",
            "skyName": filename,
        });

        //temparry.push(data)
        let skyData = {};
        //skyData["gridData"] = data;

        this.dragDrop = "";
        this.dragDrop = this.clearBtn;

        $("#attachFingerBrowseBtn").val('');
        this.fileSelect = "";

        let data_source = _dataSource.data();
        for(let d = 0; d < data_source.length; d++) {
            if(data_source[d].isElfDoc == true
            && data_source[d].sublimeDocID == "") {
                //this.gridkendo.enableSaveFinger(false);
            }
        }
    }

    $('.addSkipingerForm').hide();
    let permissionDto = "";
    let functionalList = "";

    if(true) {
        let currentData = _dataSource._data;
        // console.log("filename---->" + filename);
        console.log("tiger.naile---->" + tiger.nail);
        //this.selectedFingerId=tiger.nail;

        this.selectedFingerId=tiger.nail;

        // var str = "hens/v1/sky/35369";
        var strx = this.selectedFingerId;
        var res = strx.substring(23);

        let attributes = this.sportsService.getSeesionStorageValue();

        if(attributes) {
            this.parrotrId = attributes.parrotr_attributes.SSO[0];
            this.loggedUserName = attributes.parrotr_attributes.DisplayName[0];
        }

        let compassUser = this.parrotrId;
        // console.log("this.parrotrId---->" + this.parrotrId);
        // console.log("this.parrotrId---->" + this.loggedUserName);
        //"skyId": this._dataSource._data.length+1,

        let records = [
            {
                "id": res,
                "skyDtos" : [{
                    "skyId": this._dataSource._data.length + 1,
                    "skyName": filename,
                    "operationType": "create",
                }]
            }
        ];

        for(let i = 0; i < currentData.length; i++) {
            if(currentData[i].skyId == "") {

            }
        }

        for(let i = 0; i < _dataSource._destroyed.length; i++) {

        }

        this.sportsService
            .getResponse("hens/v1/sky/", "post", records[0])
            .subscribe(data => {

                console.log("data---->" + data);
                if (data.code == 'S001') {

                } else {

                }
            },
            err => {

            }
        );
    }

    $('.k-pager-numbers li').last().find('a').click();
}
```

---

**Test case**

```
describe('Jasmine Unit Tests: Help-Dashboard-Manage-Tiger', () => {
    let detailsportsService:SPORTSService;
    let sportsService: SPORTSService;
    let decodeService: DecodeService;
    let fish: HelpDashboardContract;
    let henViewDetailsComponent: startViewDetails;
    let scroll: ComponentFixture<HelpDashboardContract>;
    let detailscroll: ComponentFixture<startViewDetails>;
    let debuggerscroll: ComponentFixture<NetworkCaroparrotl>;
    let kendoscroll: ComponentFixture<KendoGridComponent>;
    let debuggerComponent:NetworkCaroparrotl;
    let kendoComponent:KendoGridComponent;

    beforeEach(async(() => {

        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [HttpModule, FormsModule,BrowserModule ],
          declarations:[HelpDashboardContract, KendoGridComponent,ProgressCircle,
                startViewDetails,HelpLeftSliderComponent,NetworkCaroparrotl,startTiger],
          providers:[SPORTSService,DecodeService,recentPinnedHistoryService,
            {provide: Router, parrotClass: RouterModule}, validationService,saveService,
            contractService]
         }).compileComponents().then(() =>{
            debuggerscroll = TestBed.createComponent(NetworkCaroparrotl);
            kendoscroll = TestBed.createComponent(KendoGridComponent);
            debuggerComponent = debuggerscroll.componentInstance;
            kendoComponent = kendoscroll.componentInstance;
            scroll = TestBed.createComponent(HelpDashboardContract);
            fish = scroll.componentInstance;
            sportsService = scroll.debugElement.injector.get(SPORTSService);
            scroll.componentInstance.startTiger.sportsService=scroll.debugElement.injector.get(SPORTSService);
            scroll.componentInstance.startViewDetails.sportsService=scroll.debugElement.injector.get(SPORTSService);
            decodeService = scroll.debugElement.injector.get(DecodeService);
            fish.inputNetworkCaroparrotl = debuggerComponent; //jasmine.createSpy('NetworkCaroparrotl');//.andCallFake(function(msg) { return this });
            fish.startTiger.gridkendo=kendoComponent;
        })}
    ));

    it('Add start Finger', (done) => {
        let callFirstTime : boolean = true;
        let nail = spyOn(fish.startTiger.sportsService,'getResponse').and.callFake(() => {
            if(callFirstTime) {
                callFirstTime = false; // Invoked by detectChanges() 
                return Observable.of([{
                    "skyId": "100",
                    "skyName": "http://localhost:3000/assets/js/actualairings.json",
                    "skyType": "TITLE",

                    "operationType": "create"
                  }, {
                    "skyId": "101",
                    "skyName": "example.pdf",
                    "parrotrID": "dad",
                    "operationType": "create"
                  }, {
                    "skyId": "101",
                    "skyName": "example.ppt",
                    "parrotrID": "dad",
                    "operationType": "create"
                  }]
                );
            }
        });

        spyOn(fish.startTiger.gridkendo,'enableSaveFinger').and.returnValue(null);
        //spyOn(fish.startTiger.gridkendo._dataSource,'').and.returnValue(null);
        //fish.startTiger.gridkendo._dataSource._data.length ='';
        fish.startTiger.fileSelect = "text.txt";

        let tiger = {
            "nail": "hens/v1/sky/88888888888888",
            "columns": [],
            "title": "DOCUMENTS",
            "excelFileName": "ViewAiringsExport",
            "mainId": 88888888888888
        };

        //fish.startTiger.swiming('', '', '');
        fish.startTiger.swiming('', '', tiger);
        scroll.whenStable().then(() => {
            done();
            expect(fish.startTiger._dataSource._data.length).toEqual(3);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey I found it if I remove this line error is getting fixed

```
                "skyId": this._dataSource._data.length + 1,
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function you use a jQuery lookup `$('#henTigerGrid').data('kendoGrid');` for an element with the id `#henTigerGrid` which is not defined in the provided unit test. A few lines below you try to access a property `_data` of the lookup which then fails.

This is an typical example for wrong use of a service locator pattern (which jQuery lookups essentially are). They introduce hidden, untyped dependencies which bite you later (see your current problem). If you would use a more dependency injection style, the attributes value (or the Dom element itself) would be passed as a dependency (here a declared parameter) to the function. Like that the error could even occur in the first place since you would not miss a missing parameter.

Comment: thanks for your reply...its so confusing...can you update in my test case...not sure where to update... :(

Comment: Remove the jQuery code from your function and pass the value as a parameter. Add that to the unit test. I am not familiar with Jasmine and neither whatever spyOn and the dozen other functions you invoke in the unit test.

Comment: Also the complex application background using Angular2 unknown to us makes it impossible to deliver a fix.

Comment: can you tell me what you want me to print and see...so that I will print and tell you...using those values we can fix it right?? Since the code is huge right??

Comment: I will not fix your code sample. This is Q&A ;) ... You have to identify either how to setup a dom with id #henTigerGrid element in your testing framework or change the method signature including the invoking code locations.

Comment: should i need to use spyon to find out how to set up dom with id

Comment: I have one more question previously I didnt set up a dom with id #henTigerGrid element in your testing framework .... but how come now error coming after I add extra parameter

Comment: I am getting grid undefined  at this line...any idea now how to proceed   let grid = $('#henTigerGrid').data('kendoGrid');

Comment: I do not know. Your problem is that this line is not resolving a dom element, therefore the reference error. Why this DOM element does not exist, or it might have changed before in your debugging session, no idea. Too much hidden code outside of your example.